# Use Cases for DebuggerStepThroughAttribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Question is pretty straight forward. Are there any valid use cases for the [`DebuggerStepThroughAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? *Valid in the sense that they'd be used in a development environment.*

Losing 4 solid hours, only to find this attribute decorated on a class is rather disheartening.

Comment: This question, however, is probably something that will only give opinions, and not facts, so I'm voting to close it as such.

Comment: Boring auto-generated code, mostly.

Answer (score 2):

I have used it when developing framework code, when the source code to the framework is in the same solution as the main application.

Basically when done with the framework code, I tag the appropriate classes or methods, so that if I, as an example, step over a method call up in the application code, it will not suddenly dive into tons of framework code before resurfacing in the application code somewhere else.

Makes it easier to debug the application.

Comment: This makes very good sense. I guess the idea is to be aware of its usage. This sounds like the most plausible answer. Thanks Lasse ...